# Stacking Random Numbers

Tags: random, stack

I wanted to stack random numbers and printout the stack.
I tried to write the code but I can`t find where the problem is coming from`
Please tell me what I did wrong, thank you a lot

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 100

int main()
{
    typedef struct {
        int key;
    } element;

    int stack[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    int top = -1;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int i;

    void push(element, int i);
    {
        if (top >= MAX_STACK_SIZE)
        return;
        for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            i = rand() % 10;
            stack[top++] = i;
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<=10; i++)
        printf("%d", stack[i]);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could could you specify please, what is exactly not working or what you are expecting? It seems, your code sample is incomplete.

Comment: Thank you a lot for replying. I tried to stack random numbers and print them out in order but it did not work. So could you tell me which part is incomplete??

Comment: Your code seems to have problems: (1) I suspect, `void push(...); {...}` is a function. If it is, you'd better carry that function out of the scope of the `main` function (and of course, you have to remove the `;` before opening the functions first curly brace). (2) Type definitions as well are better out of the scope of the `main`. Maybe, you need to revisit a good C book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to implement a stack. Regarding your provided code and the missing informations what exactly is not working (compiler error?), I tried to migrate it to a working piece of code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 100

typedef struct {
    int key;
} element;

element NULLKEY;

element stack[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
int top = -1;

void push(element el)
{
    if (top >= MAX_STACK_SIZE)
        return;  // Handle out of range

    stack[++top] = el;
}

element pop()
{
    if (top < 0)
        return NULLKEY; // Handle out of range

    element el = stack[top];
    top--;
    return el;
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int i;

    element el;

    el.key = 5;
    push(el);

    el.key = 20;
    push(el);

    el.key = 10;
    push(el);

    for (i=0; i<=3; i++)
        printf(" %d ", stack[i].key);

    for (i=0; i<=3; i++)
        printf(" %d ", pop().key);
}
```

- `push(element)` pushes a new element on the stack
- `pop()` returns latest element and removes it from the stack
- with `stack[index]` you can still iterate it.